# Why does Brainiac look like a frog in "The Dark Knight Strikes Again"?

Tags: dc, comics, frank-miller, brainiac, dark-knight-strikes-again

In the second half of "The Dark Knight Strikes Again" by Frank Miller, Brainiac shows up over Metropolis to fight Superman. Instead of his normal appearance, however, his ship/body looks like [a giant toad](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Brainiac_(Earth-31)). Then later we see him perched on the top of Luthor's shoulder, presumably in his real body, and it is the same frog-like appearance - only smaller.

As far as I know, Brainiac has always appeared in a humanoid form, with his ships often resembling a disembodied head with tentacles. **Has Miller or anyone else associated with the comic discussed why this drastic change in Brainiac's physical appearance?**

Comment: Because Frank Miller is an atrocious artist.

Comment: @RogueJedi - Because Frank Miller is so far up himself that he's in danger of turning inside out.